# Get product min_price by sku

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get the smallest value of `min_price` by sku for product `post_type` and draft `post_status`.

```
function get_product_min_price_by_sku($sku) {
  global $wpdb;
  $min_price = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare("
      SELECT MIN(min_price) 
      FROM {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} 
      WHERE sku = '$sku'
    ")
  );
  return $min_price;
}
```

How can I add the post status condition to this function?

```
AND posts.post_status = 'draft'
```

BTW. I allow multiple products with same sku:

```
add_filter('wc_product_has_unique_sku', '__return_false', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter the query via the `post_status` we first need to look for the value in the correct table which is the wp posts table, we can do so by updating our SQL query using the JOIN statement and match the correlating values in multiple tables, in this case we are matching the *product_id* in the `wp.posts` table with the one in the `wp.postmeta` table.

The tables we are matching using the JOIN statement:

- wp.posts `$wpdb->posts`
- wp.postmeta `$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup`

Below is an updated function:

```
function get_product_min_price_by_sku( $sku ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $min_price = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            SELECT MIN(lookup.min_price) 
            FROM {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} AS lookup
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON lookup.product_id = posts.id
            WHERE
            posts.post_type IN ( 'product', 'product_variation' )
            AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
            AND lookup.sku = '%s'
            LIMIT 1
            "
        , $sku)
    );

    return $min_price;
}
```